# Summation of logarithmic functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum of series $\frac{(\log3)^1}{1!}+\frac{(\log3)^3}{3!}+\frac{(\log 3)^5}{5!}+\cdots$ is what?
Is there a general algorithm to find the summation of logarithms?

Comment: Maybe a Taylor series?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The series itself does not have too much to do with logarithms; to see why without getting lost with the $\log$ everywhere, let $\alpha = \log 3$. You want
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\log 3)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sinh \alpha
$$
by [the series definition of $\sinh$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions). That being said, now here we have simplifications because $\alpha=\log 3$. Indeed, recall that, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\sinh x = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
$$
and therefore here
$$
\sinh \log 3 = \frac{e^{\log 3}-e^{-\log 3}}{2} = \frac{3-1/3}{2} = \boxed{\frac{4}{3}}\,.
$$

Comment: I was wondering what taylor series it was, forgot about hyperbolics.

Comment: @ClementC: if we don't recognize which Taylor Series, what is a good procedure? This one is odd, and tends to +/-infinity.

Comment: @smci You always have the option of trying a formal math software, e.g. Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha, to get a hint "recognizing" the series. But otherwise, here, would you have recognized it with a $(-1)^n$ in each term? (to get $\sin$) If so, then recognizing $\sinh$ is not too hard. Or you could directly recognize something like "only the odd indices of $\exp$", so that thinking of $\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$ (the odd part of $\exp$) is natural.

Comment: **Or** if you really don't recognize anything, try to find some differential equation the series satisfies (differentiating to get termwise derivatives, then reorganizing); solving the differential equation would in many case allow you to find the corresponding function.

Comment: For instance, here differentiating twice the power series we get $$f''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)2n \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = f(x)$$ so that solving $f''=f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$ will give you the solution $f=\sinh$.

Comment: @ClementC.: thanks for the refresher. You might like to put them in your answer.